# Delete Async Files & Subfolder and Show Status Percentage in Progressbar

Tags: c#, file, timer, count, percentage

Basically i have a folder with some files and other folders (with files too) inside, and i would like to perform a master deletion by showing the percentage of the action in two progress bar windows form controls.
The first progress bar should show "x file from y files from z directory is being deleted" and the 2nd progress bar the overall process percentage.

Example for 1st progress bar: Deleting (1/100) D:\folder\file.extension
(where 1 is the number of the file being deleted, 100 is the files count from that folder) But if someone can show me a way to make it with only 1 progress bar too (the 1st one), it would be really helpful.

This is my code so far:

```
 private int deleted = 0;
 private int total = 0;

    private void RemoveDirectories(string strpath)
    {
        if (Directory.Exists(strpath))
        {
            DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(strpath);

            foreach (FileInfo file in dirInfo.GetFiles())
            {
                //file.Delete();
                total += (int) file.Length;
                deleted /= 1024;
                progressBar1.Step = deleted;
                progressBar1.PerformStep();

            }
            foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in dirInfo.GetDirectories())
            {
                //dir.Delete(true);
                total += dir.GetFiles().Length;
                deleted /= 1024;
                progressBar1.Step = deleted;
            }
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RemoveDirectories(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\\dex");
    }
```

Comment: And your problem is...

Comment: My problems is that i can't display with the progress bar any of what i would like to do....

Comment: That's all the code i wrote, and basically the progress bar doesn't move at all, i tried to read many other example and useless, so right now im waiting for someone to show me an example so i can learn from it for future usings.

Comment: There are some errors: 1- deleted is ALWAYS 0, so it will not do anything, 2.-Step means how much the bar will be incremented, it should be 1. 3- You did not set the Max value, so it will be always 100 4-You did all of this on the UI thread, it will block the UI until the op is finished, so even if you correct the previous bugs you will see just a jump from 0 to max, you need to do this in a worker thread and update the UI using Invoke()

Comment: And finally... youre not deleting any file/fodler at all...

Comment: I understand what are you saying Gusman, but an example would be more helpful for me...

Comment: Yes, im not deleting, beceacause first i wanted to "count the files" to see if the progress bar actually does what it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some errors:

1- deleted is ALWAYS 0, so it will not do anything
   2-Step means how much the bar will be incremented, it should be 1
   3- You did not set the Max value, so it will be always 100 
   4-You did all of this on the UI thread, it will block the UI until the op is finished, so even if you correct the previous bugs you will see just a jump from 0 to max, you need to do this in a worker thread and update the UI using Invoke()

Here is your function modified:

```
    private void RemoveDirectories(string strpath)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) =>
        {
            if (Directory.Exists(strpath))
            {
                DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(strpath);
                var files = dirInfo.GetFiles();
                 //I assume your code is inside a Form, else you need a control to do this invocation;
                this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
                    progressBar1.Value = 0;
                    progressBar1.Maximum = files.Length;
                    progressBar1.Step = 1;
                }));

                foreach (FileInfo file in files)
                {
                    //file.Delete();
                    this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => progressBar1.PerformStep())); //I assume your code is inside a Form, else you need a control to do this invocation;

                }

                var dirs = dirInfo.GetDirectories();

                this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    progressBar1.Value = 0;
                    progressBar1.Maximum = dirs.Length;
                }));

                foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in dirs)
                {
                    //dir.Delete(true);
                    this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => progressBar1.PerformStep())); //I assume your code is inside a Form, else you need a control to do this invocation;
                }

            }
        }, null);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but this isn't working...The progressbar starts loading a bit and then stoppes, and it's value remains 1.

Comment: I tested it and works, you should have an error somewhere else or you did not copied the code exactly as is

Comment: There is no error, i'm calling the function from a button.

Comment: God, sorry, there is an error, on my test case files and dirs where of same size, let me modify it

Comment: By me not at all...is loading until value 1.

Comment: Yeah i kind of see the progressbar loading full, but if the main path is 300 mb or 1 gb length, the progressbar seems like not to be very affected, and also the progressbar value shows to 1. I mean if the files in the path are 1 gb all together, the progress bar should load more slower, am i right?

Comment: No, the progress bar is counting how many files you deleted, not the size of the file.

Comment: but even so, the progress bar is loading very fast for delting 1.95 GB from a folder...

Comment: Because you're not deleting anything may be?

Comment: well take a look in both our codes, the commented line "file.Delete()"; ...is actually deleting everything, but the progress bar still NOT accordingly to it..

Comment: but it's commented... and as I said, it's a progress on HOW MANY FILES are deleted no HOW MANY BYTES are deleted.

Comment: The progressbar to perform its loading based on the ammount of bytes being collected to be deleted. That's what i want you to edit in your answer. my dear friend Gusman.